# Is OpenGL an API or software library?

Tags: opengl

There are many questions that explain the difference between API and library like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678665/is-there-still-a-difference-between-a-library-and-an-api) and [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54451/library-vs-framework-vs-api).

I understand that a library is a chunk of code that you can call from your own code, to help you do things more quickly/easily. An API is a part of a library of classes and methods which can be used by a user in their code. From my understanding, I classified OpenGL as a library not an API but when I read a book it says OpenGL is not a library it is an API.

Can you tell me which it is?

Comment: `when i read a book it says opengl is not library it is API` Book is not always right. Apply your own mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenGL is an API. Why? Because an API is a list of functions and tokens that are specified to behave in a certain way. An API is written down in a *specification*. The specification of OpenGL can be found at http://opengl.org/registry and specifications by itself are not something you can install and run on a computer system.

OpenGL is not a library. Why? Because a specification is just a normative text, which is something you can not use standalone. Note that among the specification documents for OpenGL there are also header files that can be use to compile a OpenGL program. But what's missing is actual code (library) that could be linked against. Something that can be linked against and behaves like specified by the OpenGL specification is called an *implementation*. But implementations are tied to the very same OpenGL specification and shipped as part of a operating system's graphics infrastructure.